# What's wrong with GitHub GraphQL API?

Tags: github, graphql

I have a query for getting commits from specific repository:

```
query($repository: String!, $repositoryName: String!, $after: String, $since: GitTimestamp!, $until: GitTimestamp!) {
    repository(owner: $repository, name: $repositoryName) {
        refs(refPrefix: "refs/heads/", first: 100) {
            pageInfo {
                hasNextPage
                endCursor
            }
            edges {
                node {
                    name
                    target {
                        ... on Commit {
                            history(first: 100, after: $after, since: $since, until: $until) {
                                nodes {
                                    oid
                                    committedDate
                                    message
                                    associatedPullRequests {
                                        totalCount
                                        nodes {
                                            state
                                            reviews {
                                                totalCount
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    author {
                                        email
                                        name
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except one moment: for some reason `associatedPullRequests` field is always null, but some commits definitely have pull requests.

Funny thing is that if I request only `totalCount` in `associatedPullRequests` it works fine